# pyautogui distance between 2 or more objects

Tags: python, pyautogui

im tryin to make it move to player (detected image or texture) and then scan for near by objects like images or textures
my code:
it looks for an image in the screen and moves mouse to it

```
import pyautogui
def detect():
    L1 = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('danger/player.png')
    pyautogui.moveTo(L1)

while True:
    detect()
```

but i have no idea how do i make it detect if [IMAGE] is near the mouse position,
can somebody help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

To find out of the image is near the mouse position, you'll need to find the distance between them.

If the image is found `pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(image_path)` will return a pair `(x, y)` for the centre of the image.
`pyautogui.position()` will also return a pair `(x, y)` for the mouse position.

You can then find out the distance between them. For example: [`math.dist(p, q)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.dist) will give you the Euclidean distance between the two coordinates `p` and `q`.